# Команда apt update возвращает ошибку

Tags: linux, update, sudo, apt

```
root@kali:~# apt update
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: relocation error: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode, version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: relocation error: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode, version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: relocation error: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls.so.30: symbol _idn2_punycode_decode, version IDN2_0.0.0 not defined in file libidn2.so.0 with link time reference
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Method https has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process https returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/https did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/14.04/prod/dists/trusty/InRelease
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас в системе битые пакеты. Решите сначала эту проблему. Например:

```
aptitude purge ~b
```

Comment: Не спасёт) тут линковка у апт поломанна уже

Answer (score 1):

у меня ошибка ушла после того как я поменял зеркала в источнике приложений которые были ближе к моему местоположению